# How to pass variables with get_template_part?

Tags: include, get-template-part

I am developing a custom theme and i like to pass some variables to selected files. I am calling the view files from functions.php.

```
$var1 = ;
$var2 = ;
etc
include_once('form-views/view-profile.php');//works

//get_template_part('includes/form-views/view','profile');//doesn't work
```

Now with include it works

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially scope visibility issue. `include` brings code into a current scope, function call creates new closed off scope. In `get_template_part()` only certain WordPress globals are being made available by [`load_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/load_template/) call inside.

While the basic answer is to declare your variables as globals, you might want to ponder your overall architecture a bit — this is typically not a good sign in code.

Comment: do you mean i should avoid using include? I thought i was doing a better architecture by using a view and have a function deciding which view to load.

Comment: @alex I mean avoiding relying on globals to pass information around

Comment: i don't use globals with the include version. At the moment i am trying https://github.com/Smartik89/SMK-Theme-View/blob/master/functions.php which looks ok. It wraps the load_template function in another function. But it adds more code?

Comment: Oh and then you access the variables as `$this->var`? Clever ...

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, I usually use:

```
include(locate_template('includes/form-views/view-profile'));
```

In this way, a child theme can override the file.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 5.5 allows passing $args to get_template_part. Apart from this function there are sets of template function which can now accept arguments.

```
get_header
get_footer
get_sidebar
get_template_part_{$slug}
get_template_part
```

Please refer more details at: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/